# Using nnet for prediction, am i doing it right?

Tags: r, machine-learning, neural-network, idioms

I'm still pretty new to R and AI / [ML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Machine_learning) techniques. I would like to use a neural net for prediction, and since I'm new I would just like to see if this is how it should be done.

As a test case, I'm predicting values of `sin()`, based on 2 previous values. For training I create a data frame with`y = sin(x)`, `x1 = sin(x-1)`, `x2 = sin(x-2)`, then use the formula `y ~ x1 + x2`.

It seems to work, but I am just wondering if this is the right way to do it, or if there is a more idiomatic way.

This is the code:

```
require(quantmod) #for Lag()
requre(nnet)
x <- seq(0, 20, 0.1)
y <- sin(x)
te <- data.frame(y, Lag(y), Lag(y,2))
names(te) <- c("y", "x1", "x2")
p <- nnet(y ~ x1 + x2, data=te, linout=TRUE, size=10)
ps <- predict(p, x1=y)
plot(y, type="l")
lines(ps, col=2)
```

Thanks

### [edit]

Is this better for the predict call?

```
t2 <- data.frame(sin(x), Lag(sin(x)))
names(t2) <- c("x1", "x2")
vv <- predict(p, t2)
plot(vv)
```

I guess I'd like to see that the nnet is actually working by looking at its predictions (which should approximate a sin wave.)

Comment: The `predict()` call looks suspicious. Aren't you just predicting 'y' with 'y'? On the other hand it might be failing to actually be supplying newdata, since it is not a dataframe. So you would just be "predicting" with the lagged values in 'te'. You might look at `expand` to avoid needing "pkg:quantmod"

Comment: i added a better example for predicting, do you think that would be actually using the nnet model? it seems to give a sin when plotted

Comment: You can check by plotting the original on the same scale as the predicted:  `plot(x, vv);  lines(x, y)` and you see there is a lag (which it seems you would expect.)

Comment: An example in [here](http://www.parallelr.com/r-deep-neural-network-from-scratch/) about R + DNN for better understand.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

I really like the `caret` package, as it provides a nice, unified interface to a variety of models, such as `nnet`.  Furthermore, it automatically tunes hyperparameters (such as `size` and `decay`) using cross-validation or bootstrap re-sampling.  The downside is that all this re-sampling takes some time.

```
#Load Packages
require(quantmod) #for Lag()
require(nnet)
require(caret)

#Make toy dataset
y <- sin(seq(0, 20, 0.1))
te <- data.frame(y, x1=Lag(y), x2=Lag(y,2))
names(te) <- c("y", "x1", "x2")

#Fit model
model <- train(y ~ x1 + x2, te, method='nnet', linout=TRUE, trace = FALSE,
                #Grid of tuning parameters to try:
                tuneGrid=expand.grid(.size=c(1,5,10),.decay=c(0,0.001,0.1))) 
ps <- predict(model, te)

#Examine results
model
plot(y)
lines(ps, col=2)
```

It also predicts on the proper scale, so you can directly compare results.  If you are interested in neural networks, you should also take a look at the `neuralnet` and `RSNNS` packages.  `caret` can currently tune `nnet` and `neuralnet` models, but does not yet have an interface for `RSNNS`.

/edit: `caret` now has an interface for `RSNNS`.  It turns out if you email the package maintainer and ask that a model be added to `caret` he'll usually do it!

/edit: `caret` also now supports Bayesian regularization for feed-forward neural networks from the [brnn](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/brnn/index.html) package.  Furthermore, caret now also makes it much easier to specify your own [custom models](http://caret.r-forge.r-project.org/custom_models.html), to interface with any neural network package you like!

Comment: thanks very much, that looks great. Sorry for the delay in response somehow i missed the notification of a reply

Comment: + Nice example. Your answer is first hit for search on '[r] nnet predict'.