# NA impact in Caret Train

Tags: r, na, r-caret, training-data

Following the example reported in the link below I have the following error:

[Using nnet for prediction, am i doing it right?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7743768/using-nnet-for-prediction-am-i-doing-it-right)

> Error in na.fail.default(list(y = c(0, 0.0998334166468282, 0.198669330795061,  :    missing values in object

To solve this error I use the condition **na.action = na.omit**

```
#Fit model
model <- train(y ~ x1 + x2, te, method='nnet', linout=TRUE, trace = FALSE,
               #Grid of tuning parameters to try:
               tuneGrid=expand.grid(.size=c(1,5,10),.decay=c(0,0.001,0.1)),
               na.action = na.omit) 
ps <- predict(model, te)

is.na(te)
nrow(te)
nrow(ps)
```

Is this condition the only way to proceed?

In fact the consequence is that the number of rows of the ps is different to the number of ps data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you are lagging the data, this is probably the best approach. Note that:

```
> sum(!complete.cases(te))
[1] 2
```

The model can't predict these which is why

```
> nrow(ps)
[1] 199
> nrow(te)
[1] 201
```

and this is because:

```
> formals(predict.train)$na.action
na.omit
```

(**Note** that this will probably be changed to `na.fail` in the next version of the package)